# Using exceptions from a module without importing it explicitly

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, python-import

I have an utility module `utils.py` that uses [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/) to perform some tasks. In the client code (that uses `utils`) I need to handle exceptions thrown by `requests`, but I'd like to avoid importing `requests` implicitly (in the client, that is). How can I achieve that?

`utils.py` is (simplified)

```
 import requests

 def download(url):
     # stuff
     return requests.get(url)
```

and I want the `client.py` to be something like

```
 import utils  # <-- no "import requests"

 try:
      utils.download(whatever)
 except HTTPError:  # <-- not "requests.exceptions.HTTPError"
      do stuff
```

`except utils.something` would work too. The name doesn't need to be global. All I want is to avoid mentioning `requests` anywhere in the client.

For those wondering, this is simply a matter of separation of concerns. `client.py` shouldn't care how exactly `utils.download` is implemented and what underlying lower-level library it uses.

Comment: Python only actually imports once no matter how many `import requests` statements you execute.  You can verify this by putting `print "request has been imported` in the request module at module scope.  It will only be printed once.

Comment: So, you mean importing all of utils.py without importing something in utils.py (requests)?

Comment: @Jblasco: I don't want the word "requests" to occur anywhere in client.py.

Comment: In `utils.py` add `HTTPError = requests.exceptions.HTTPError` and then in `client.py` use `except utils.HTTPError:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: You can't (or at least, shouldn't).

Of course, there is no reason to avoid importing anything you want to use. That is how Python works, is intended to work, and works best.

If you really want to separate the concerns, make `download()` catch the exception, and throw a new `utils.DownloadError` exception.

```
def download(...):
    try:
        ...
    except HTTPError as e:
        raise DownloadError() from e
```

Edit:

Long answer: You can actually do this, by chain importing the exception - but I'd highly recommend against it - it just makes the code less clear.

E.g: If you do `from requests.exceptions import HTTPError` in `utils.py`, then you can `import utils` and use `utils.HTTPError`.

I believe, however, this can be more fragile - not to mention roundabout and harder to track the intention in the code. I still highly recommend against it.

From a separation of concerns point of view - it may well stop you mentioning `requests`, but it still relies on the exception, so all it is doing is hiding the concern, not separating it.

Comment: @thg435 The answer remains the same.

Comment: @thg435 I lied a little, there is a way to do this, but it's not a good way.

Comment: @thg435 It's just [a little feature added for 3.x](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) that means you keep that exception around so you can see the root cause of the top exception when debugging - it's not vital. Just don't use the `from` part in older versions. Obviously, you might want to make the new exception carry some information the original exception carries - but that's all dependant on your usage.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a **shabby** way of doing it, but I would do one of two things:

- Deal with the exceptions inside utils.py or...
- Note the exceptions within utils.py and re-raise an HTTPError in case of requests.exceptions.HTTPError

Would you be happy with any of those two?

Comment: "re-raise" is the problem - there's far more than just HTTPError

Comment: And are you going to make an except for each of them? because if you are going to go one by one with all the exceptions you will have the same problem anyway, right? It is a matter of where you will deal with them and how many of them you will deal independently with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `utils.requests.exceptions.HTTPError`, but you can't avoid "mentioning" `requests`. All you can do is mention it in a roundabout, error-prone way.